# no puedo subir imagen a directorio con php

Tags: php, html

buen dia a todos, tengo el siguiente form:

```
<form action="include/cargar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3"    name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div class="form-group text-center col-8">
        <span>Foto de perfil</span>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="perfil">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 text-center">
          <button type="submit" class="btn text-white"  name="crear">Publicar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente: que al darle clic al boton publicar, se cree una carpeta con el id y el nombre que se pone en el input y a su vez que la imagen se suba a dicho directorio, lo que hago es lo siguiente:

```
<?php
include('cnx.php');
$nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($cnx, $_POST['nombre']);
$perfil= mysqli_real_escape_string($cnx, $_POST['perfil']);

$insert = "INSERT INTO `publicaciones` (`nombre`) VALUES ('$nombre')";
$carga = mysqli_query($cnx, $insert);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM publicaciones";
$query = mysqli_query($cnx, $sql);

while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$carpeta = "../img/".$r['id']."_".$r['nombre'];
if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
mkdir($carpeta, 777);
$nombre = $_FILES[$perfil]['name'];
$nombrer = strtolower($nombre);
$cd=$_FILES[$perfil]['tmp_name'];
$ruta = $carpeta."/". $_FILES[$perfil]['name'];
$destino = $carpeta."/". $nombrer;
$resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$perfil]["tmp_name"], $ruta);
}
```

pero esto me arroja los suiguientes errores:

Notice: Undefined index: perfil in /opt/lampp/htdocs/proyectos/pagina/include/cargar.php on line 10
Notice: Undefined index: in /opt/lampp/htdocs/proyectos/pagina/include/cargar.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: in /opt/lampp/htdocs/proyectos/pagina/include/cargar.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined index: in /opt/lampp/htdocs/proyectos/pagina/include/cargar.php on line 24

no se por que no me trae el dato del file $perfil
y no se porque me dice que no hay una variable definida con el nombre in si es que no creo ninguna variable con ese nombre. alguno me daria una mano con esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En estricto rigor `$_POST['perfil']` no existe, si revisamos tu formulario podemos darnos cuenta que ese valor es un `input` de tipo `file` y el valor de ese input se encontrarará en `$_FILES['perfil']` y no en `$_POST['perfil']`.

Para renombrar la imagen puedes utilizar el siguiente código, si estás recibiendo un `array` de datos este código debe ir dentro de la iteración.

```
$extension = explode(".", $_FILES['perfil']['name']);
if(!isset($extension[1])){
  echo "El fichero subido no cuenta con una extensión";
  //Controla la excepción con tus reglas de negocio acá
}else{
  $extension = $extension[1];
  //Renombramos la imagen
  $_FILES['perfil']['name'] = "perfil.$extension";
}
```

Comment: ya he solucionado lo de la carga de la imagen
ahora lo que me gustaria hacer y no encuentro como es que al cargar la imagen en la carpeta la pueda renombrar con la palabra perfil:
se que tengo que usar la funcion str_replace pero no le encuentro la manera, la uso asi pero nada:
 $n_final = str_replace($nombrer, "perfil", $nombrer);

Comment: A la hora de guardar el fichero físicamente puedes asignarle el nombre

Comment: con str_replace?

Comment: Sigo con el problema de que no puedo subir la imagen con el nombre que quiero. Me podrían ayudar? Antes de subirla a la carpeta recién creada quiero renombrar la a perfil más la extensión que tenga dicha imagen. Ayuda x favor

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, espero que te sirva como guía. Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias.